# Delete node at given position in a circular doubly linked list

Tags: c

I'm working in a "media player" I need to use a circular doubly linked list to store all the songs, however I need a function that deletes the node at a given position, my function seems to work well when there are more than 1 node but if there's only one node it will keep displaying the deleted node until i add another song to the list.

My header file.

```
typedef struct node Node;
typedef struct smediaplaylist Smediaplaylist;

struct node {
    char name[26];
    char artist[26];
    int date;
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
};

struct smediaplaylist {
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
};
```

Delete function:

```
void delete_song(Node** head,int position){
   // IF LIST IS EMPTY 
    if ((*head) == NULL || position <= 0){
    printf(RED"\nNo existe la cancion en la lista de reproducción\n"R3SET);
        }

    if((*head)!=NULL || position>0){
    Node* new_node = (*head);
    // SEARCH NODE POSITION
    for (int i = 1; new_node != NULL && i < position; i++){
        new_node = new_node->next;
    }
    // IF GIVEN POSITION IS > THAN AMOUNT OF NODES
    if (new_node == NULL){
    printf(RED"\nLa cancion no esta dentro de la lista de reprodución\n"R3SET);
    }else{
    // WE SEND THE NODE TO DELETE TO DELETE NODE FUNCTION
    deleteNode(head,new_node);
    }
    }
} 

void deleteNode(Node** head, Node* tobedelete){
    char choice;
    printf(YELLOW"\nDatos de la canción a eliminar:"R3SET);
    printf(CYAN"\nNombre de la cancíon:%s",tobedelete->name);
    printf("\nNombre del artista:%s",tobedelete->artist);
    printf("\nAño de lanzamiento:%d"R3SET,tobedelete->date);
    printf(YELLOW"\nDesea eliminar[S/N]:"R3SET);
    getchar();
    scanf("%c",&choice);

    if(choice=='S'){
    if ((*head)== NULL || tobedelete == NULL){
        return; 
    }
    // IF NODE IS THE HEAD OF OUR LIST
    if ((*head) == tobedelete){
        (*head) = tobedelete->prev;

    }
    // RE LINK NODE ONLY IF NEXT NODE ISN'T NULL
    if (tobedelete->next != NULL){
        tobedelete->next->prev = tobedelete->prev;
    }
   // RE LINK PREVIUS NODE ONLY IF IS'NT FIRST NODE
    if (tobedelete->prev != NULL){
        tobedelete->prev->next = tobedelete->next;
    }
    // FREE NODE
    free(tobedelete);
    printf(GREEN"\nCanción eliminada correctamente...\n\n"R3SET);
    }if(choice=='N'){
    printf(GREEN"\n Operación abortada\n\n"R3SET);
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    if(choice!='S' && choice!='N'){
        printf(RED"\n Operacion cancelada no se ingreso una opcion valida\n"R3SET);
    }
}
```

Example:
My list is:

1. Hotel california - Eagles - 1996
2. Creep - Radiohead - 1993

after delete song 2 my list is:

1. Hotel california - Eagles - 1996

After deleting song 1 my list should be empty, but it will keep displaying the deleted node until I add a new node.

1. Hotel california - Eagles - 1996

Comment: `if ((*head) == tobedelete){ (*head) = tobedelete->prev` This is a bit suspect.

Comment: It is suspect. When you have only 1 node in a circular list, the node is self-referencing (e.g. `head->prev = head->next = head;`) So you must check `if (*head == (*head)->next)` and free and then set `*head = (*head)->prev = (*head)->next = NULL;`

Comment: In method `delete_song` you have this line of code: `if (new_node == NULL){` How can `new_node` be null in a circular list?

Comment: Only if the list is empty... Also `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior on virtually all but MS compilers. `fflush()` is only defined for *"seekable"* streams in standard C. Better `for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}`

Comment: Thanks to all I have managed to solve it.

Comment: The newer question you posted [today] got closed and then you deleted it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68170401/segmentation-fault-while-reading-and-tokenizing-a-txt-file I had been working on a solution when that happened. Here is a pastebin link with the refactored and working code: https://pastebin.com/SxJMdBdX that will expire in one week.

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate it.